# How to display the increasing data?

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code, if one clicks the "increase" button, the number will go up by 0.1 per second. If one clicks the button again, it will go up by 0.2 per second, and it goes on and on. I would like to display the increasing rate (+.../s) on the screen, how do I do this?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73bya1c5/)

```js
let num = document.getElementById("num");
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let Increment = 0;

function toIncrease() {
  Increment += .1;

  if (Increment == .1) {
    setInterval(() => {
      num.innerHTML = parseFloat(parseInt((parseFloat(num.innerHTML) + .05 + Increment) * 10) / 10);
    }, 1000)
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", toIncrease)
```

```html
<span id="num">0</span> <br>
<span id="incSpeed">(+0/s)</span>
<button id="btn">
increase
</button>
```

Comment: Same way you're displaying `num`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added 2 lines to your code,

```js
let num = document.getElementById("num");
let incspeed = document.getElementById("incSpeed");
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let Increment = 0;

function toIncrease() {
  Increment += .1;
  incspeed.innerHTML = `(+${Increment}/s)`;

  if (Increment == .1) {
    setInterval(() => {
      num.innerHTML =
        parseFloat(parseInt((parseFloat(num.innerHTML) + .05 + Increment) * 10) / 10);
    }, 1000)
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", toIncrease)
```

```html
<span id="num">0</span> <br>
<span id="incSpeed">(+0/s)</span>
<button id="btn">
increase
</button>
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the code! But there is a small problem: the number would jump to +0.799999999 instead of +0.8 or + 0.299999999 instead of + 0.3. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Replace the `(+${Increment}/s)`; with `(+${Increment.toFixed(1)}/s)`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes @AndrevKurkov , you can use toFIxed like I did in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70545503/295783) from the start. Also you do not need the parseFloat(parseInt(parseFloat as I demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

To update the text I used template literals

```
incSpeedSpan.innerHTML = `(+${incSpeed}/s)`
```

The `parseFloat(parseInt((parseFloat(num.innerHTML) + .05 + Increment) * 10) / 10);` is unnecessary

I also set a variable to hold the setInterval return value so you can clearInterval if needed

```js
const num = document.getElementById("num");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const incSpeedSpan = document.getElementById('incSpeed');
let incSpeed = 0;
let tId;
function toIncrease() {
  incSpeed += .1
  if (!tId) {
    tId = setInterval(() => {
      num.innerHTML = (+num.innerHTML + incSpeed).toFixed(1); // make sure to round the decimals
    }, 1000);
  }
  incSpeedSpan.innerHTML = `(+${incSpeed}/s)`;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", toIncrease);
```

```html
<span id="num">0</span> <br>
<span id="incSpeed">(+0/s)</span>
<button id="btn">
increase
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should works.

```js
 let num = document.getElementById("num");
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let Increment = 0;
let speed= document.getElementById('incSpeed')
function toIncrease() {
  Increment += .1;
  if(Increment == 0.1){
  setInterval(() => {
        speed.innerHTML = '(+'+Increment.toFixed(1)+'/s)'
      num.innerHTML = parseFloat(parseInt((parseFloat(num.innerHTML)+.05+Increment)*10)/10);
    }, 1000)
}
  }


btn.addEventListener("click", toIncrease)
```

```html
    <span id="num">0</span> <br>
<span id="incSpeed">(+0/s)</span>
<button id="btn">
increase
</button>
```